# Texture not Rendering correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]I dont know, Where is am doing wrong. I have downloaded an image  [image]

Which is wooden wall with panel background.

I have created a material to fix it on the object wall (imported from blender) and I am getting just a plane color, not like the above lines in between the wooden wall.

[image]

I have used almost each shader one by one, Legacy Shader, Unlit Shader. But why i am not getting the same texture.. Please help how can i get the same texture on my wall.??

Comment: Have you unwrapped the object in blender? You need to create a UV map. https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping.html

Comment: how did you create the 3d mesh of the wall? is the texture displayed correctly, when you use a Unity default 3D objects mesh ? (e.g. GameObject > 3D Object > Sphere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unwrap the texture in blender or some other software

Comment: Thanks, I raised a blender question for this problem here also - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61513/acrhimesh-texture-problem  and both of you has helped.. thanks :-)

Comment: ok :) you have to select the face you want open a second window with the UV/Image Editor an apply the texture on it.
1) 3D-View; Select Faces you want
2) 3D-View: find in the left shelf UVMapping and click on Unwrap or Smart UV Project or sth else..
3)Open second window with UV/Image Editor
4)Choose your Texture....

Comment: That I know Perazim, how to uv map in blender.. Anyways thanks  a lot. Its a great help :-)